# How does sklearn know which columns are One-Hot encoded?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have a data set where there are columns that are of type object and others of type int or float. I understand that I need to convert the object columns to dummy variables but I also have some int and float columns that represent binary data (already 0 and 1). Will sklearn interpret these columns as categorical or not? I do not want these to be treated as continuous variables.

Comment: "sklearn" has functions and classes that process data. "Sklearn" does not interpret your dataframe as such

Answer (score 0):

`OneHotEncoder` does not process, which are the columns are categorical type. Hence, all the columns that are fed to `OneHotEncoder` would be converted into dummy variables.

You can refer to the examples [here](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

If you already have binary variables and then it doesn't make sense to create two dummy variables for it.

You can use `make_column_transformer` to specify the columns that you need one hot encoding.

Example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> X = pd.DataFrame([['Male', 0], ['Female', 1], ['Female', 0]], columns=['gender', 'groups'])
>>> from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
>>> ct = make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(),[0])) #, remainder='passthrough'
>>> ct.fit_transform(X)
array([[0., 1.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.]])
```